# What records in my PrestaShop database do I need to remove to clean up the data

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

We have an eCommerce Prestashop (ver 1.7.2) shop. Our initial testing is okay and our shop is ready for deployment. We need to remove the order records to have a clean version of the shop. What table records do we need to remove?

Answer (score 3):

Search in your Modules Catalog for cleaner, the full name is PrestaShop Cleaner.
Install it and give it a go.
Official statement:

> PrestaShop Cleaner can only be managed from the back office. It allows you to roughly clean your store by deleting your whole catalog, orders, and customers.
>
> For example, this module allows you to suppress all demo data in one go. But this module must be used carefully: once you delete it all, there is no possible rollback. Everything is removed for good.

Comment: Thanks, but I couldn't get Prestashop Cleaner to install. Is there any cache to delete, etc?

Comment: Why you couldn't install it? Is there an error message? Enable the Debug from Advanced Preferences -> Performance and see if you get any error message.